# Kafka engine table in Clickhouse works wrong on a cluster

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse cluster with 6 nodes, configured with 2 shards and 3 replicas

- shard1: cdh01, cdh02, cdh03;
- shard2: cdh04, cdh05, cdh06;

I created a Kafka engine table and use a **MATERIALIZED VIEW** to write data to the local table with a **ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree** engine. All tables are created on each node with **ON CLUSTER {cluster_name}**.

Now I found all data are writen to the local table on nodes of shard1, and there is no data in the local table on nodes of shard2. And the amount of data on nodes of shard1 is seemed to be not correct.

I collect the debug log on node cdh06, and got logs like:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHlry.png).

There are several tables with similar settings created before and read data from different kafka-topics which are working correctly. But now when creating such tables, the problem above would happen.

Comment: `shard` term usually mean data in different shards shall be different, could you share 

`SELECT engine_full FROM system.tables WHERE name='<your_replicated_merge_tree_table_name>'` 

moreover maybe https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-integrations/altinity-kb-kafka/
could help you understand what exactly this engine work?

Comment: The result is " ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/cas_sso_logs/{shard}', '{replica}') PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192"


Now I execute "select count() from {local_table}", and get 0 on the nodes of shard2. Actually I have created several tables with similar sql before, and they work correctly. It seems now the new table **got  empty assignment** on the kafka topic